# Blocks and templates storing approach in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

Since the loading time is too significant I wrote this question. I have a php script which contains multiple templates and some `side` and `center` blocks. Each block contain a small php code to print some statistics, or random news.

In my control panel I am able to open these files and start editing without opening the file. Now there are some people want to share the script with me, and I am looking for the best storing method to store my template and blocks content.

## The First Approach

- Store each block and template file in the database.
- Each block contain position and content and title.
- Each template contain 20 content files such as `css`, `header`, `fotter`, `index`, `block` and `contact_us page`.
- In the home page:

  - Get default theme from `database`. [20 files].
  - Get all blocks that and each block layout will be generated using `block.php` from the default theme.

The real problem is that getting `20` `mediumtext` + `20` `text` for blocks is too big when I try to edit and `RELOAD` my page.

## The Second Approach

- Is to save all these files in the server, and using open file stream to read, edit and save.

## Third Approach?

---

***My Question here is: What is the best approach to store and get files like that.***

Comment: I'd recommend the second approach. And use the DB to store only which template to use. Look into how WordPress does their themes.

Comment: @bobthyasian I am going to make people change the templates in the `Control Panel`, so I can put some information about the file variables and some notes. If I used `WordPress` approach they will need a full documentation to be able to edit.

Comment: 1. 'make'? Or do you mean allow? 2. You could use file stream to edit the files but use Jquery (or equivalent) to simplify the editing process. Am I kinda answering your question or just going down a different avenue?

Comment: Sorry for that, I mean allow. Yes your idea is nice, but I need to control the `theme` and `blocks` directories using php. When the admin create new block, I have to create a new file `block_name.php` ? and put the content in the file?

Comment: Hmm. I personally, from what I can gather from your question, would be to have the Themes be files and used as templates with the layout, then store the blocks' settings and blocks' contents in a DB.